Copiar archivos renombrados automáticamente con CMD BAT No entra al FOR en la segunda
Tengo el código
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
color 8f
chcp 65001
cls
goto inicio

::--------------------INICIO DE FUNCIONES-------------------------

:CopiarArchivos
    set /p LetrRenom= Letra de archivos a nombrar: 
    set "ruta=C:\Users\Maestro"
    set "rutaDestino=C:\Users\Maestro\folder"
    set /a cuenta=1
    set "Extension=.png"

    for %%f in (!LetrRenom!*!Extension!) do (
        set "NombreActual=%%~nxf"
        set "NombreActualSinExt=%%~nf"
        :: Verifica si el archivo ya existe en la ruta de destino
        if exist "!rutaDestino!\!NombreActual!" (
            echo "El archivo !NombreActual! ya existe, renombrando."
            pause>nul
            :verificarExisteArch
            set nuevoNombre=!NombreActualSinExt!!cuenta!!Extension!
            if exist "!rutaDestino!\!nuevoNombre!" (
                set /a cuenta+=1
                goto verificarExisteArch
            )
            :: Copiar con el nuevo nombre
            copy "!ruta!\!NombreActual!" "!rutaDestino!\!nuevoNombre!"
            echo "Archivo copiado y renombrado como: !nuevoNombre!"
            pause>nul
        ) else (
            :: Copiar el archivo si no existe en la ruta de destino
            copy "!ruta!\!NombreActual!" "!rutaDestino!\!NombreActual!"
            echo "Archivo copiado como: !NombreActual!"
            pause>nul
        )
    )
cls
goto inicio

a (1)1.png
a (1)2.png
a (1)n.png
a (2)1.png
a (2)2.png
a (2)n.png
Lo que hace es que agarra los archivos a (1).png y a (2).png, se ejecuta una primera vez y los renombra y los copia en el escritorio tantas veces desde el número 1 hasta n
correctamente
Pero lo ejecuto una segunda vez y solo hace el proceso de renombrar el archivo a (1).png
pero el archivo 1 (2).png lo ignora, ya no entra al For para ahora hacer el proceso con 1 (2).png
sabrán si hay que moverle algo a la lógica de CMD o windows o algo me falla en la lógica de programación.

Sin entrar en mucho análisis del bat debo comentar que el uso de un GOTO dentro de un bucle FOR "rompe" el bucle incluso aunque el destino del GOTO esté dentro del bucle FOR. Para comprobarlo sugiero que pruebes este sencillo ejemplo
@echo off
for /l %%a in (1,1,5) do (
   echo Vamos por el %%a
   goto seguir
   :seguir
   echo Sigue y sigue
   )

Si "comentas" el GOTO (precediéndolo de REM) verás que sale lo siguiente:
Vamos por el 1
Sigue y sigue
Vamos por el 2
Sigue y sigue
Vamos por el 3
Sigue y sigue
Vamos por el 4
Sigue y sigue
Vamos por el 5
Sigue y sigue

Sin embargo si dejamos que se ejecute el GOTO saldrá lo siguiente:
Vamos por el 1
Sigue y sigue

Por tanto en cuanto se ejecute el "goto verificarExisteArch" se saldrá del bucle FOR y creo que esto explica el comportamiento de tu script

Interesante. Debe haber una explicación para tal conducta; si pudieras explicarla sería estupendo.

Ya me gustaría, pero no la he encontrado. Tuve problemas hace tiempo cuando intentaba usar saltos dentro de un FOR y al final decidí probar con un ejemplo sencillo que demostraba lo que he dicho, pero no lo he encontrado reflejado en ningún sitio

Pero acabo de ver esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552664/windows-batch-goto-inside-for-loop
